How to decompose JavaScript in hugo js build
I make website using Hugo and p5
On one page I have several skethes with p5 canvas.
So something like this
sketch_1.js

import p5 from 'js/libs/p5.min.js';
import math from 'js/libs/math.js';
{
  new p5(m);
   ...
}

sketch_2.js, sketch_3.js ...
As you can see I import p5., math and I also import some local files.
After that I build page with shortcode like
include_sketch.html

...
{{ $js := resources.Get $abs_sketch_path | js.Build | resources.Minify }}
 
<script async src="{{ $js.RelPermalink }}"></script> 
...

And everything's working BUT. js.Build just copy all content from p5 and other libs to sketch_N.js file.
So I have all sketches with average size like 1 Mb with copy of p5 and so on.
Is there a way to decompose files and import it like modules. So I would download only one p5.
I look docs from
Hugo js Build and read some forums but don't find the solution
I expect file decomposition.
So browser download only one p5.js and only one math.js and so on


"So browser download only one p5.js and only one math.js and so on". What do you mean by it ? browser will request p5/math.js only once (very first time) and saves it in cache, if other scripts (lets say sketch_99.js) tries to import p5/math,  it loads from cache thus avoids network requests.


When hugo js.Build creates a final js file, it copies and pastes all imported files into the final js. If I have several final js files on pages with a common libs, it will insert libs into each file

If $abs_sketch_path points to sketch_X.js, you can't decompose. Hugo won't know how to decompose a JS script.
What you can do is importing and merging in Hugo. Something like this:
{{ $p5_js := resources.Get "js/libs/p5.min.js" }}
{{ $math_js := resources.Get "js/libs/math.js" }}

Then merge the different javascripts yourself in Hugo.
